# Heroku outputs too much in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, heroku

Ever since I started to use my own procfile I see in the logs pointless (for production env) data such as

```
Feb 19 09:10:09 myapp app/web.1:  Processing by PagesController#launch as */* 
Feb 19 09:10:09 myapp app/web.1:    Rendered devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb (4.4ms) 
Feb 19 09:10:09 myapp app/web.1:    Rendered pages/launch.html.erb within layouts/application (20.0ms) 
Feb 19 09:10:09 myapp app/web.1:    Rendered layouts/_suggest.html.erb (0.7ms)
```

How do I disable such rendering logs (that belong to development and not production)?

Comment: I'm not so certain those logs are pointless. What if you wanted to profile rendering performance of your production site?

Comment: true, if I wanted to. but on production with many users this makes logs impossible to go through and too big..

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding one of the [logging add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/#logging) to your application. That will make it much easier to analyze and act on your logs.